# How do I delete a line from the table in index page when I press the delete button without deleting it from the database

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server, visual-studio, model-view-controller

How do I delete a line from the table in index page when I press the delete button without deleting it from the database.
i'm using asp.net mvc5 with visual studio 2017 and sql server 2016.

```
// GET: Information/Delete/5
    public ActionResult Delete(int? id)
    {
        if (id == null)
        {
            return new HttpStatusCodeResult(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest);
        }
        Information information = db.Informations.Find(id);
        if (information == null)
        {
            return HttpNotFound();
        }
        return View(information);
    }

    // POST: Information/Delete/5
    [HttpPost, ActionName("Delete")]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public ActionResult DeleteConfirmed(int id)
    {
        Information information = db.Informations.Find(id);
        db.Informations.Remove(information);
        db.SaveChanges();
        return RedirectToAction("Index");
    }

    protected override void Dispose(bool disposing)
    {
        if (disposing)
        {
            db.Dispose();
        }
        base.Dispose(disposing);
    }
}
```

}

this code delete the selected row from database. i want to delete it just from index page.
Please could anyone give me any hint.

Answer (score 0):

If you delete it only from the Index page, the row will appear again when the page is loaded.

However, you can delete it using jquery.

In your Index View write this:

```
<script>
    $(".class").on("click", function(){   //if your element has a class
         $(this).remove();
    })
    $("#id").on("click", function(){     //if your element has an id
         $(this).remove();
    })
</script>
```

Comment: thank you so much! but where i can write this? maybe here? public ActionResult DeleteConfirmed(int id)
    {
        Information information = db.Informations.Find(id);
        db.Informations.Remove(information);
        db.SaveChanges();
        return RedirectToAction("Index");                                                                         
                                                                                                                    
      sorry i'm just a beginner!

Comment: No, the code that i've written is in JavaScript, while your controllers are in C#.

Comment: so how can i write it in C# ? and where i should write it ?

Comment: i write the code in the end of my index view code, but it still remove the line from my database. should i delete something here from the controller?:  public ActionResult DeleteConfirmed(int id)
    {
        Information information = db.Informations.Find(id);
        db.Informations.Remove(information);
        db.SaveChanges();
        return RedirectToAction("Index");
    }

Comment: my index view has three buttons after each line, and a table shows what in my database. the buttons are edit, details and delete. when i click at delete button another page will loaded shows me the details of the line selected and one delete button. when i click it the line is disappears from the table and from the database. i want it to disappear just from the table. the code in my controller remove the line selected from the database so the line disappears also from the table because it shows what in my database..

Comment: That's the default behavior of ASP.NET. The easiest way is to delete those buttons from the View and put buttons with HTML. Put a class on those buttons and the code above should work. However, it will remove the button, not the whole line. Write .parent() as many times as needed and in the end it will delete the whole row.

Answer (score 0):

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function () {
      function deleteRow() {           
                var par = $(this).parent().parent();
                par.remove();
            };
            $("#Tableid").on("click", "#btnid", deleteRow);
    });
    </script>
```

Write This Code in Index Page

"#Tableid"= id of Your Table,

"#btnid" = id of Your Delete Button(Which is unique for all Delete Buttons of Table)

This Code Only remove column on a page level not from database,

if you reload page you get back all the data

if you have any queries please ask

Answer (score 0):

You can just use the jquery remove() method to remove that row..
Just you have something to target that row i.e. id or a class

$('#ID').remove();
OR
$('.CLASSNAME').remove();

Answer (score 0):

thank you everyone. i solve the problem when i write this code in the controller:
return View(db.Informations.Where(f=>f.show== true).ToList());
"show" is a checkbox. if a select it in the create page so the row will appears in the index page, if not it will appears just in the database.
so i need the delete button just to remove the selected row to be invisible in the index page.
I apologize for my weak English.
thank you